# How to run sdelete with a whatif flag

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I'm writing a PowerShell script finding directories with `Get-ChildItem` and passing them to `sdelete`. I would like to trial run it. I don't think `sdelete` has a `-WhatIf` flag. Is there any way I can achieve something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement the `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm` functionality by adding `SupportShouldProcess` to the CmdletBinding statement at the top of your function and a `if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess(something) { }` block to your code.

For example:

```
Function Remove-WithSDelete {
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess,ConfirmImpact="High")]
  Param ($File)

  Process {
    if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($File)) {
        & sdelete.exe $File
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
PS C:\> Remove-WithSDelete c:\temp -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Remove-WithSDelete" on target "c:\temp".
```

The `ConfirmImpact` part is optional and is used to define the level at which `-Confirm` is invoked automatically. If the impact level of the function is equal to or greater than your `$ConfirmPreference` level, `-Confirm` will be the default behaviour (without explicitly invoking it. You can force it off by doing `-Confirm:$false`). If you omit it your function Confirm Level is "Medium" by default. The default level of the `$ConfirmPreference` variable is "High".

Comment: Paused halfway through a `Remove-item ...  -WhatIf` workaround answer to try this. Works like a charm.